# How do I fix the error "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" for my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a battleship game and for this part of the code the directions are:
Write a function `addShips(grid, numShips)` which loops until it has added `numShips` ships to the grid. For each time through the loop, it should create a ship using `createShip()`, then `checkShip` for that ship on the given grid. If the returned `not_clear` list is empty, then the ship can be placed.

So far my function is:

```
def addShips(grid, numShips):
    createdShips = [] 
    x = 0
    while x < numShips:
        createdShips.append(x)
        x = x + 1
        
    for ship in createdShips:
        not_clear = checkShip(grid, ship)
        if not not_clear:
            for loc in ship:
                grid[loc[0]][loc[1]] == 2
    return grid
```

It runs fine until it gets to the line `not_clear = checkShip(grid, ship)` and then when it calls `checkShip(grid,ship)`:

```
def checkShip(grid, ship):
    arr = []
    for loc in ship:
        if grid[loc[0]][loc[1]] != 1:
            arr.append(loc)
    return arr
```

I get:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

on the line `for loc in ship:`. The function `checkShip(grid, ship)` runs fine by itself but when I have to call it from `addShips` I get the error. What can I do about it? Can someone help me fix the code instead of just explaining what the error means? (I understand the error I just don't know how to fix it, which is my question)

Comment: Are you aware that `createdShips` is simply `range(numShips)`?

Comment: We can't help you fix it without understanding what the code does or at least having a [mre] to run... It is not clear what you expect `createdShips` to be (it is just a list of numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Created ships is an array filled with ints (done by the line `createdShips.append(x)`)

The line `for loc in ship` is then trying to iterate over each ship, however as previously stated, each ship is just a number

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate over a number, You would need a list, which ship isn´t.

In this sentece `checkShip(grid, ship)` you give ship to the function `def checkShip(grid, ship):` which wants to iterate over a number in `for loc in ship:` which isnt possible!

Answer (score 0):

When iterating over data, it should be always an iterable data type like a list, array, or a dictionary. In your case check the datatype of **ship** and convert as required